# Uploaded Videos still get marked as "Private(locked)" even after Youtube API was verified

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube, youtube-data-api

For work, I am using an internal tool written in Google app script to upload videos from company Google Drive to YouTube channels through the insert() method.
I have gone through the application for Youtube API verification, got approved successfully and even have the daily token quota increased. However, all of the videos uploaded through the tool continue to be marked as private(locked) by Youtube automatically.

I am 99% sure that it is not because of the content of the videos, but very likely because of the API. I tried uploading the same videos twice: first through the tool and then manually: only the ones uploaded through the tool get locked as private. This happens 100% of the time. I also do not have the option to appeal for the videos,  matching the description "For videos that have been locked as private due to upload via an unverified API service, you will not be able to appeal".

**My setup:** The app script code (attached to a google sheet file) handle the upload code. The app script in turn is connected to a Google cloud Project (unverified app since it is meant for internal use) with Youtube API enabled (This API is verified)

So does anyone know how to fix this?

Tried creating another app script, logged into another computer - same thing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem! If anyone is having the same issue: check the IAM permission of the email you are using to upload to Youtube [(this part in the setting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQMPc.png)
In the Gooogle Cloud project, that email MUST have the IAM admin access, otherwise all video uploaded will be marked as private.

Hope this helps